# How to do digital image processing using opencv on Eclipse

Tags: opencv, cmake, eclipse-juno

I am new to Digital Image Processing and want to do it using OpenCV on Eclipse. I just want to know how can i start doing it and how i can configure opencv and eclipse using CMAKE . Please suggest me some good tutorial.Also please help me with adding opencv include files and library in Eclipse.
I am using Eclipse Juno.
on Windows 7.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to begin with the OpenCV documentation. Their [Getting Started](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Getting_started) tutorial should be your first stop. They have another strategy with a custom FindOpenCV.cmake file as documented [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/FindOpenCV.cmake) but I would suggest sticking with the strategy outlined in Getting Started.

In terms of eclipse, cmake generates IDE related metadata for you and Kitware does provide an eclipse CDT generator, documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9453851/how-to-configure-eclipse-cdt-for-cmake). Two important things to keep in mind. First cmake actually generates the eclipse metadata which you then import as an existing project. Second, the example they give is intended to work with Unix makefiles:

```
cmake -G"Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles" -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ../certi_src
```

If you are using windows you'll want to choose an appropriate [generator](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Generator_Specific_Information#Makefile_generators) instead of "Unix Makefiles"