# CMake Error: Could not create named generator Visual Studio 14 2015 win64

Tags: caffe

I want to use caffe deep learning. when I want to run caffe-windows\build_win I recive an error.what is problem? how can I resolve it?
caffe is best for deep learning and I want to use it. I installed anaconda, visual studio 2015, cmake, cuda and I want to use caffe now.

```
C:\Users\mohsen\Desktop\Propozal\DeepLearning\Install option for caffe\caffe-win
dows>scripts\build_win
The system cannot find the drive specified.
The system cannot find the drive specified.
INFO: ============================================================
INFO: Summary:
INFO: ============================================================
INFO: MSVC_VERSION               = 14
INFO: WITH_NINJA                 = 0
INFO: CMAKE_GENERATOR            = "Visual Studio 14 2015 win64"
INFO: CPU_ONLY                   = 0
INFO: CUDA_ARCH_NAME             = Auto
INFO: CMAKE_CONFIG               = Release
INFO: USE_NCCL                   = 0
INFO: CMAKE_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS    = 0
INFO: PYTHON_VERSION             = 3
INFO: BUILD_PYTHON               = 1
INFO: BUILD_PYTHON_LAYER         = 1
INFO: BUILD_MATLAB               = 0
INFO: PYTHON_EXE                 = "python"
INFO: RUN_TESTS                  = 0
INFO: RUN_LINT                   = 0
INFO: RUN_INSTALL                = 1
INFO: ============================================================
CMake Error: Could not create named generator Visual Studio 14 2015 win64

Generators
  Visual Studio 15 2017 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2017 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
  Visual Studio 14 2015 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2015 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
  Visual Studio 12 2013 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2013 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
  Visual Studio 11 2012 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2012 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
  Visual Studio 10 2010 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2010 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "IA64".
  Visual Studio 9 2008 [arch]  = Generates Visual Studio 2008 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "IA64".
  Visual Studio 8 2005 [arch]  = Generates Visual Studio 2005 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64".
  Visual Studio 7 .NET 2003    = Deprecated.  Generates Visual Studio .NET
                                 2003 project files.
  Borland Makefiles            = Generates Borland makefiles.
  NMake Makefiles              = Generates NMake makefiles.
  NMake Makefiles JOM          = Generates JOM makefiles.
  Green Hills MULTI            = Generates Green Hills MULTI files
                                 (experimental, work-in-progress).
  MSYS Makefiles               = Generates MSYS makefiles.
  MinGW Makefiles              = Generates a make file for use with
                                 mingw32-make.
  Unix Makefiles               = Generates standard UNIX makefiles.
  Ninja                        = Generates build.ninja files.
  Watcom WMake                 = Generates Watcom WMake makefiles.
  CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeBlocks - NMake Makefiles = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeBlocks - NMake Makefiles JOM
                               = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeBlocks - Ninja           = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles  = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeLite - MinGW Makefiles   = Generates CodeLite project files.
  CodeLite - NMake Makefiles   = Generates CodeLite project files.
  CodeLite - Ninja             = Generates CodeLite project files.
  CodeLite - Unix Makefiles    = Generates CodeLite project files.
  Sublime Text 2 - MinGW Makefiles
                               = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files.
  Sublime Text 2 - NMake Makefiles
                               = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files.
  Sublime Text 2 - Ninja       = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files.
  Sublime Text 2 - Unix Makefiles
                               = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files.
  Kate - MinGW Makefiles       = Generates Kate project files.
  Kate - NMake Makefiles       = Generates Kate project files.
  Kate - Ninja                 = Generates Kate project files.
  Kate - Unix Makefiles        = Generates Kate project files.
  Eclipse CDT4 - NMake Makefiles
                               = Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files.
  Eclipse CDT4 - MinGW Makefiles
                               = Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files.
  Eclipse CDT4 - Ninja         = Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files.
  Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles= Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files.

ERROR: Configure failed

C:\Users\mohsen\Desktop\Propozal\DeepLearning\Install option for caffe\caffe-win
dows>
C:\Users\mohsen\Desktop\Propozal\DeepLearning\Install option for caffe\caffe-win
dows>scripts\build_win
The system cannot find the drive specified.
The system cannot find the drive specified.
INFO: ============================================================
INFO: Summary:
INFO: ============================================================
INFO: MSVC_VERSION               = 14
INFO: WITH_NINJA                 = 0
INFO: CMAKE_GENERATOR            = "Visual Studio 14 2015 win64"
INFO: CPU_ONLY                   = 0
INFO: CUDA_ARCH_NAME             = Auto
INFO: CMAKE_CONFIG               = Release
INFO: USE_NCCL                   = 0
INFO: CMAKE_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS    = 0
INFO: PYTHON_VERSION             = 3
INFO: BUILD_PYTHON               = 1
INFO: BUILD_PYTHON_LAYER         = 1
INFO: BUILD_MATLAB               = 0
INFO: PYTHON_EXE                 = "python"
INFO: RUN_TESTS                  = 0
INFO: RUN_LINT                   = 0
INFO: RUN_INSTALL                = 1
INFO: ============================================================
CMake Error: Could not create named generator Visual Studio 14 2015 win64

Generators
  Visual Studio 15 2017 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2017 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
  Visual Studio 14 2015 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2015 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
  Visual Studio 12 2013 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2013 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
  Visual Studio 11 2012 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2012 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
  Visual Studio 10 2010 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2010 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "IA64".
  Visual Studio 9 2008 [arch]  = Generates Visual Studio 2008 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "IA64".
  Visual Studio 8 2005 [arch]  = Generates Visual Studio 2005 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64".
  Visual Studio 7 .NET 2003    = Deprecated.  Generates Visual Studio .NET
                                 2003 project files.
  Borland Makefiles            = Generates Borland makefiles.
  NMake Makefiles              = Generates NMake makefiles.
  NMake Makefiles JOM          = Generates JOM makefiles.
  Green Hills MULTI            = Generates Green Hills MULTI files
                                 (experimental, work-in-progress).
  MSYS Makefiles               = Generates MSYS makefiles.
  MinGW Makefiles              = Generates a make file for use with
                                 mingw32-make.
  Unix Makefiles               = Generates standard UNIX makefiles.
  Ninja                        = Generates build.ninja files.
  Watcom WMake                 = Generates Watcom WMake makefiles.
  CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeBlocks - NMake Makefiles = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeBlocks - NMake Makefiles JOM
                               = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeBlocks - Ninja           = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles  = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeLite - MinGW Makefiles   = Generates CodeLite project files.
  CodeLite - NMake Makefiles   = Generates CodeLite project files.
  CodeLite - Ninja             = Generates CodeLite project files.
  CodeLite - Unix Makefiles    = Generates CodeLite project files.
  Sublime Text 2 - MinGW Makefiles
                               = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files.
  Sublime Text 2 - NMake Makefiles
                               = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files.
  Sublime Text 2 - Ninja       = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files.
  Sublime Text 2 - Unix Makefiles
                               = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files.
  Kate - MinGW Makefiles       = Generates Kate project files.
  Kate - NMake Makefiles       = Generates Kate project files.
  Kate - Ninja                 = Generates Kate project files.
  Kate - Unix Makefiles        = Generates Kate project files.
  Eclipse CDT4 - NMake Makefiles
                               = Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files.
  Eclipse CDT4 - MinGW Makefiles
                               = Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files.
  Eclipse CDT4 - Ninja         = Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files.
  Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles= Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files.

ERROR: Configure failed

C:\Users\mohsen\Desktop\Propozal\DeepLearning\Install option for caffe\caffe-win
dows>
```

Comment: i think it has to do with your Visual studio Cmake generator...try Eclipse and see

Comment: Thank you. But how can I use Eclipse?

Comment: refer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9453851/how-to-configure-eclipse-cdt-for-cmake

Comment: I am beginner and I could not resolve my problem. I could not understand those steps. would you please  guide me easier?